# ag-grid prevent rowDrop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid with row dragging enabled. I need the user to be able to drag and drop all rows **except** for the first row. The first row must remain in place at index 0. The issue I am seeing is that, while my code below works just fine to disable **dragging** the row at index 0, users can still **drop** other rows into index 0. I want to prevent this.

Here is a simplified version of my component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

const AgGrid = () => {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null)
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
    {Name: "name1", Type: "type1", Draggable: false},
    {Name: "name2", Type: "type2", Draggable: true},
    {Name: "name3", Type: "type", Draggable: true}
  ]}

  const columnDefs= [
    {
      field: 'Name',
      rowDrag: ({data}) => data.Draggable
    },{
      field: 'Type'
    }
  ]
  
  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine">
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        onGridReady{(params) => setGridApi(params.api)}
        rowDragManaged={true}
      />
    </div>
  )
})
```

I hoped there would be a rowDrop prop or some mechanism by which to keep a row in place, but I can not seem to find it if something like that exists.

**Note**

I tried unmanaged dragging, but found myself writing a ton of logic just to keep that single row in place. If there was a simple `onRowDragStarted` and `onRowDragEnded` event, it would certainly be simpler to implement. I ran into a lot of issues because of the behavior described on their [website](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/row-dragging/#row-drag-events), and quoted below:

"If the drag is finished outside of the grid, then the `rowDragLeave` is the last event fired and no `rowDragEnd` is fired".

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `rowDragMove` event and don't let the row at index 0 move at all, and don't allow any row to move to index 0.

While using unmanaged row dragging, set the `rowDragMove` event to:

```
  onRowDragMove = (event) => {
    if (event.node.id === 0)
    {
      return;
    }
    var movingNode = event.node;
    var overNode = event.overNode;
    var rowNeedsToMove = movingNode !== overNode;
    if (rowNeedsToMove) {
      var movingData = movingNode.data;
      var overData = overNode.data;
      var fromIndex = immutableStore.indexOf(movingData);
      var toIndex = immutableStore.indexOf(overData);
      var newStore = immutableStore.slice();
      moveInArray(newStore, fromIndex, toIndex);
      immutableStore = newStore;
      this.gridApi.setRowData(newStore);
      this.gridApi.clearFocusedCell();
    }
    function moveInArray(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
      if (toIndex === 0)
      {
        toIndex = 1;
      }
      var element = arr[fromIndex];
      arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
      arr.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
    }
  };
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/GtylRIYnjYZW6fuv).

Comment: This worked great! I needed to change `event.node.level === 0` to `event.node.id === 0` because all nodes have level 0 (unless grouping), and therefore nothing could move. After the minor change, it works as expected. Thank you!